# trying to solve ACM 295 (fatman). Looking for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve ACM problem [295](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/2/295.pdf). The problem basically says that there is a set of point obstacles in a corridor which is W units wide and L units long. I need to find the widest
object that can go from left to right avoiding those point obstacles. My initial thinking was to somehow do a depth first search to find all possible paths through the set of obstacles. But cannot formulate the algorithm.

Can anyone give a hint on which direction I should think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [UVa 295](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_295). You will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Maximum Flow problem for me.